# how to use pcntl_fork() with Apache?

Tags: php, apache, pcntl

This is my code, inside `index.php` (just an example):

```
$pid = pcntl_fork();
if ($pid == -1) {
  die("failed to fork");
} else if ($pid) {
  // nothing to do
} else {
  putDataIntoWebService();
  exit();
}
echo "normal page content";
```

This snippet works fine in command line. In Apache `exit()` kills them both, the parent and the kid process. What is a workaround?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/13105346/632951

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the solution:

```
posix_kill(getmypid(), SIGKILL);
```

instead of `exit()`.

Comment: The correct solution is to use `pcntl_wait` in the parent and writ for the child rpocesses to finish to avoid zombies. The suggested solution might or might not work, depending on the signal handlers of the children, also it's not really "healthy" to SIGKILL a process in a production code as you can't isntall signal hanler on SIGKILL and so you might leave resources hanging in the air or leave the program in an inconsistent state.

Answer (score 5):

You can't use the `pcntl_*` functions with the Apache module version of PHP. Quoting from a comment in the [`pcntl_fork` documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pcntl-fork.php):

> It is not possible to use the function 'pcntl_fork' when PHP is used
>   as Apache module. You can only use pcntl_fork in CGI mode or from
>   command-line.
>
> Using this function will result in: 'Fatal error: Call to undefined
>   function: pcntl_fork()'

Comment: you're referring to a comment at php.net, not part of an official documentation. `pcntl_fork()` does work in apache, but doesn't create a normal standalone process, I guess.

Comment: you should install `pcntl` extension then